# How to compute a tensor product with quantum states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, tensor-calculus

Say I have a state $|\psi> = ( |a_1 a_2\rangle + |b_1 b_2\rangle)$ (pure if e.g. $a_1 = a_2 = 0$ and $b_1 = b_2 = 1$

Now I want to compute $\rho = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi |$. The next step is where I might get it wrong but can I rewrite this in vector notation as

$$ \left( (a_1,a_2) + (b_1, b_2) \right)  \otimes \left(  \begin{pmatrix} a_1^* \\ a_2^*  \end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix} b_1^* \\ b_2^*  \end{pmatrix}   \right)$$

If I then use a [tensor product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) I can write this as

$$\begin{pmatrix} a_1 a_1^* & a_1 a_2^* \\a_2 a_1^* & a_2 a_2^* \end{pmatrix} + \cdots$$

The result will be a 2x2 matrix. But I read that this should be a 4x4 matrix? How should I compute $\rho$ explicitly? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is $|\psi\rangle$  "pure" only if $a_1=a_2$ and $b_1=b_2$?  It's a state vector  not a density matrix, and all state vectors  are pure by definition.

Comment: I didn't say only if, just as an example, but yes I should have written that more clearly.